# Manipulating xtable entry and print sideways

Tags: r, xtable

I have successfully created a table, that I can run as follows:

```
library(xtable)
print(x, floating.environment='sidewaystable', inlude.rownames=F)
```

Please note, that the table only fits onto the page if it is rotated sideways.

I would now like to manipulate the entries to add a `databar` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/partially-coloring-cell-background-to-fake-histogram)) command around the percentages in the table

For example:

```
x <- print(xtable(x, caption="My table"), include.rownames=F
x <- gsub("(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{2})","\\\\databar{\\1}",x)
```

The problem is that `x` is now a character vector and I can't use `print(x, floating.environment='sidewaystable', inlude.rownames=F)` any more.

I can plot the table using `cat(x, '\n')`, but of course it won't be rotated sideways then.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution could be to put the `databar` before using the `xtable` function, like this :

```
d1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), x2 = runif(6)*100)

d1
#   x1         x2
# 1  A  0.2890781
# 2  B 99.9268717
# 3  C 70.0964751
# 4  D 90.7419767
# 5  E 58.6721176
# 6  F 38.5582817

d1$x3 <- paste0("\\databar{", round(d1$x2, 2), "}")
d1
#   x1         x2               x3
# 1  A  0.2890781  \\databar{0.29}
# 2  B 99.9268717 \\databar{99.93}
# 3  C 70.0964751  \\databar{70.1}
# 4  D 90.7419767 \\databar{90.74}
# 5  E 58.6721176 \\databar{58.67}
# 6  F 38.5582817 \\databar{38.56}

library(xtable)
print(xtable(d1), sanitize.text.function=function(x) x)
# \begin{table}[ht]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{rlrl}
# \hline
#  & x1 & x2 & x3 \\ 
# \hline
# 1 & A & 0.29 & \databar{0.29} \\ 
# 2 & B & 99.93 & \databar{99.93} \\ 
# 3 & C & 70.10 & \databar{70.1} \\ 
# 4 & D & 90.74 & \databar{90.74} \\ 
# 5 & E & 58.67 & \databar{58.67} \\ 
# 6 & F & 38.56 & \databar{38.56} \\ 
# \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```

Note that you have to redefine the `sanitize.text.function` parameter, so be careful to  special characters.

Comment: thanks, I will try this out soon, the `sanitze.text.function` might have been what I was missing.

Comment: For the time being I actually solved it by doing it the other way round: I've rotated the whole page, used `xtable` and then rotated back.

Comment: just FYI that `function(x) x` is `identity` in `base`